# Какая из запятых нужна?

Tags: запятые

Какая из запятых нужна? Я думаю, что 2-я.

> Я знаю вот что: что моя мама никакой язык, кроме русского(,) — и там по-неграмотному пишет(,) — не знает и что она не стала бы сама никакого репетитора спонсировать: вечно, по еёшним словам, нищая — зато небессигаретная.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше так:

*Могу сказать, что моя мама никакой язык, кроме русского — **и там по-неграмотному пишет**, — не знает и что она не стала бы сама никакого репетитора спонсировать — **вечно, по еёшним словам, нищая, зато небессигаретная.***

**Пояснение**

1. СПП, изъяснительные отношения, вставка, запятая перенесенная.
2. В конце сообщения обособленное определение, отнесенное к личному **местоимению**. Обособляется тире.